# Can anyone help me identify the source of this noise? The whining was there previously but the rattle appeared on the journey home tonight

Tags: noise, bmw

As the title mentions, this has appeared recently, and is a little concerning. The car does not seem to be down on power, but the commute tomorrow concerns me. Any idea what this is, and whether the offending part can be replaced easily?
The car itself is a 1.9l BMW Z3.

Many thanks in advance.

[Link to video of sound. (Might be quite loud)](https://youtu.be/0D7lEh_YUsc)

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's really hard to tell on the video where it might be coming from or what it is, but if it's in the general area of where you are pointing the camera (and I'm listening to the right sound), I'm wondering if the ABS system isn't permanently running? That's what it sounds like to me, but like I said, it's *really* hard to diagnose it from the sound as a cell phone mic pics up all the noises in the engine compartment.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and the welcome. :)    I'm getting an abs warning light, which would agree with you, and the rattling noise is absent on first idle, but appears past a few thousand revs. It sounds like it's coming from underneath the throttle body, or somewhere in that area. She's just had a good service, so it's possible that the abs pump has recently gone.

Comment: You're probably going to need a stethoscope or a long screwdriver to isolate where the noise is coming from. It'd be easier if the whining sound didn't drown everything else out. Try taking the belt off and running the car see if the whine goes away. I've also seen some BMWs that had the wrong or partially restricted oil filter make a whining noise as well.

Comment: @Ben not a bad idea. Upon closer inspection, it's certainly coming from under the throttle body, so I'll take it to an approved garage and see what they say. Thanks again :)